# Spring Aspects advices being performed twice in Grails App

Tags: grails, spring-aop

I have a grails app and I've added an @After advice on a grails service method

```
class OrderManagementService {

    static transactional = true

    public void confirmOrder() {


    }
}


@Aspect
public class NotVeryUsefulAspect {


    @Pointcut("execution(* OrderManagementService.confirmOrder())")
    public void orderManagementConfirmOrder(){}

    @After("orderManagementConfirmOrder()")
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("My First Advice is working :-)");
    }


    @Around("orderManagementConfirmOrder()")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Around Method Invoked");
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

however when this method is perform this both advices are invoked twice so in the output I have

Around Method Invoked
Around Method Invoked
My First Advice is working :-)
My First Advice is working :-)

I think this has to do with the CGLIB proxy of the grails services

this is my resource.xml

```
aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"

bean id="myAspect" class="org.xyz.NotVeryUsefulAspect"


aop:config proxy-target-class="true"
```

inside of xml

any one come across this and have a solution to make it work correctly cheers

Comment: I had the same problem - http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Advice-called-2-or-more-times-for-aspect-with-execution-pointcut-Bug-td1588831.html - I had to work around it without using "execution" - http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/03/15/simple-aspects-using-annotations-in-grails/

Comment: will give this a try tomorrow cheers

Comment: that worked great Dave cheers if you want to make it an answer to get your rep up